# Unable to load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client'

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm-2013, service-fabric-on-premises

I've visual studio 2015 and I need to write custom workflow for CRM 2013. There is no error while writing workflow nor at the time of deployment. I've added this workflow to run at the on field value change. But this sent exception that `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

Any expert can please help to understand what I am missing?

Comment: Well, do you have that assembly somewhere on your dev machine? You can try running [fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to see where it probes for that assembly

Comment: No its not there

Comment: Looks like there is a nuget package for it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xrm.Client.2015/ it somehow doesn't get deployed with your stuff I guess. But there doesn't seem to be a 6.0.0. version.

Comment: this is for CRM 2015, but I am in CRM 2013 on-premise